# Que hace la funcion calc en CSS?

Tags: css

Lei las definiciones pero no entiendo exactamente su funcion, estudio un login y el codigo css viene esa funcion pero no entiendo que hace en el codigo, agradeceria si alguien pudiera explicarme

```
.formulario .password {
    width: calc(100% - 52px);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las medidas relativas en CSS pueden darnos más de un dolor de cabeza, por ejemplo usar porcentajes y márgenes puede llevar a que no se visualice bien ciertos elementos, por ese motivo existe **calc()**, una función de **CSS3** .

**Sintaxis**

```
elemento {
    width: calc(expresión);
}
```

**calc()** no solo funciona con **width**, lo podemos usar en todas las propiedades que requieran de medidas, como **height**, **background-position**, **line-height**, etc.

**Ejemplos**

```css
div {
  background-color: #FFE066;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.elemento-1 {
  width: calc(20% + 20px); /* El ancho va a ser de 20%, más 20px adicionales */
}

.elemento-2 {
  width: calc(20% - 20px) /* El ancho va a ser de 20%, menos 20px adicionales */
}

.elemento-3 {
  width: calc(20% * 2) /* El ancho va a ser de 40% */
}

.elemento-4 {
  width: calc(20% / 2) /* El ancho va a ser de 10% */
}
```

```html
<div class="elemento-1"></div>
<div class="elemento-2"></div>
<div class="elemento-3"></div>
<div class="elemento-4"></div>
```

Como puedes ver en el código, tenemos cuatro elementos con un color de fondo, alto y margen totalmente igual, pero el ancho se comporta de diferente forma (dependiendo de su operador).

Los cálculos en **CSS** nos dan bastantes opciones en nuestro código y cambia completamente la forma en que usamos las medidas.

Fuente: [Calc CSS](https://xitrus.es/blog/80/C%C3%A1lculos_en_el_CSS_con_calc()_de_CSS3)